# jquery loadBefore or loadAfter

Tags: jquery

I was wondering if anyone knows of an efficient pattern for dynamically loading html. jQuery's load method allows a developer to load html into a specified element. I would like to insert the html before a certain element. For example

html

```
<div>
   <div class ="child">
   </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
 jQuery('div.child').load('ex.html');
```

Result

```
 <div>
   <div class ="child">
        <!-- ex.html -->
   </div> 
 </div>
```

Desired Result

```
<div>
   <!-- ex.html -->
   <div class ="child">  
   </div> 
 </div>
```

I know about insertBefore and methods of this nature. But this means I have to download html into one spont and the move it all again into another spot. Does anyone have any good solutions? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will give you the proper result:

```
$GET('ex.html', function(html){
  if(html){
    jQuery('div.child').parent.prepend(html);
 }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to move anything around *after* the load; you can do something like this:

```
$('<div/>').insertBefore('.inner').load('/url');
```

as long as you can live with the div wrapping the loaded content.

Comment: i can live with that :). I will try it out. Thanks